# Java SprinBoot Security получить атрибуты в Active Directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Я использую Java + SpringBoot Security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter для авторизации в моём web приложении. Ниже рабочая конфигурация и претензий к ней нет.
после авторизации мне хотелось бы получать список пользователей или другие атрибуты из домена и далее с ним работать. Подскажите какой метод или библиотеку для этого использовать. WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, я понимаю это коннектор к домену и больше никакой функции он не выполняет?

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home", "/logout/**","/logout-success","/login/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
    authBuilder
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
            .userSearchBase("OU=Active,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru")
            .groupSearchBase("OU=Groups,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru")
            .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://regions.office.ru:389")
            .managerDn("CN=ldap_user_ro,OU=Service,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru")
            .managerPassword("passw");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск всех пользователей AD по их атрибутам (displayName):

```
public class LdapSearch {
public List<String> getAllPersonNames() {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://regions.office.ru:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=ldap_user_ro,OU=Service,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

    DirContext ctx;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    } catch (NamingException | javax.naming.NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    NamingEnumeration results = null;
    try {
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        results = ctx.search("OU=Active,OU=Users,OU=nsk,DC=regions,DC=office,DC=ru", "(objectclass=user)", controls);

        while (results.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
            Attribute attr = attributes.get("displayName");
            String cn = attr.get().toString();
            list.add(cn);
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NamingException | javax.naming.NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (results != null) {
            try {
                results.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        if (ctx != null) {
            try {
                ctx.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

}