# Java List<String> в HTML tag select

Tags: java, html, строки, list, mustache

Получаю список пользователей в виде `List<String>`: `[Петр, Иван, Демьян, ...]`

Как в Java из `List<String>` заполнить значениями форму выбора HTML

```
<select name="field1">
   <option>${list}</option>
</select>
```

или mustache:

```
<td><select name="field1">
    {{#list}}<option >{{list}}</option>{{/list}}
</select></td>
```

Если пишу

```
    List<String> listldap = app.getAllPersonNames();
       for (String list : listldap)
    model.put("list", list);
```

то получаю только последнее значение. Если

```
    List<String> list = app.getAllPersonNames();
    model.put("list", list);
```

то получаю [Петр, Иван, Демьян, ...] и количество option совпадает с количеством имён в списке. Конечно, это всё логично, но желаемого не могу получить.

Comment: Если количество option совпадает с количеством имён в списке, то что вас не устраивает?

Comment: Не устраивает то, что в каждой option содержатся все имена списка =)

Comment: Получаю список пользователей тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1187501/java-sprinboot-security-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-active-directory/1189141#1189141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> list = app.getAllPersonNames();
model.put("list", list);
```

и

```
<td>
  <select name="field1">
    {{#list}}<option>{{.}}</option>{{/list}}
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Oh my God! Thank you! Из-за этой точки я грел голову три дня!

Comment: @kent я просто заглянул в документацию. Хотя mustache никогда до этого не использовал.